# Laravel 8 view does not update routing

Tags: php, laravel, view

Hello I developing simple website. Recently I added auth(register/login) system. The problem is that when I log in to my user the routing goes to previously created route "/backend" even though I created new route called "/checkUser".
I tried to clear all kind of cache but it did not work.

**login.blade.php** *login button fragment:*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button href="{{ url('/checkUser') }}" 
        type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
            {{ __('Login') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**web.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\backendController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/checkUser', [backendController::class, 'userCheck']);
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

**backendController.php:**

```
public function userCheck()
    {
        $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
        dd($userRoles);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
Needed to check routes and find *"login"*

```
php artisan route:list
```

In my case scenario I changed *HOME* directory to "/backend"